# python script gives internal server 500 error if uploaded via cpanel but works if written in cPanel code editor

Tags: python, cgi, cpanel

Hi I have an issue with uploading files to my webhosting service at siteground.

If I upload following script to cgi-bin via file manager:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"

print "kunda"
```

and try to run it I am getting 500 internal servber error

However, if I open the file in cpanel code editor and delete the last line - save it and rewrite the line exactly the same and save again it works. I have talked to Support and tried everything. If  exactly the same file was uploaded by them it works...if uploaded by me it doesnt. Has anyone else encountyered same issue a can help me?

Thank you
Jakub

Comment: how about `Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n\n`?

Comment: nope...still 500 error :(

Comment: interestingly if i add 3 more print statements after print "kunda" it is enough to delete the last one in cpanel editor and it works....i assume it has to be something at the eof

Comment: I tried uploading via ftp and it does not work either...still have to delete the last line

Comment: my mistake...ftp transfered file works...i forgot to set permission. However cPanel transfer still does not wor even with proper 755 permision